# How to initialize a Multi-Dimensional Array in Python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I apologise if this is a duplicate question but I could not find any similar example anywhere so seeking your help.

```
lookup = {}

# These values will be filled by DB lookup service at runtime
# Maximum array length for category is unknown before program start 
# Format [Lookup Category], [Lookup Key], Lookup Id

lookup['name']['John'] = 1
lookup['name']['Jane'] = 2
lookup['name']['Joe'] = 3
lookup['gender']['Male'] = 1
lookup['gender']['Female'] = 2
lookup['country']['Japan'] = "jp"
lookup['country']['China'] = "ch"

print lookup['name']['Jane']
print lookup['gender']['Female']
print lookup['country']['China']
```

Comment: This question is extremely vague... you seem to have some sort of problem involving nested dictionaries, but that's all I can currently grasp from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

e.g.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lookup = defaultdict(dict)
lookup['name']['John'] = 1
lookup['name']['Jane'] = 2
lookup['name']['Joe'] = 3
lookup['gender']['Male'] = 1
lookup['gender']['Female'] = 2
lookup['country']['Japan'] = "jp"
lookup['country']['China'] = "ch"

print lookup['name']['Jane']
print lookup['gender']['Female']
print lookup['country']['China']
```

Comment: Amazing. This is exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate quick help. Thank you again.

Comment: @user2629996 Remember to mark the question as accepted using the green tick. Enjoy your day